# Element doesn't exist although it has ID attribute

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, iframe, webdriver

In selenium excel vba I am trying to learn more about how to deal with the CSS selectors
And I am wondering because when inspecting an element with ID and when run the code I got a message that the element not found
Here's the code till now

```
Private bot As New selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim win, mainWin As selenium.Window, sCode As String, i As Long
Dim urlImage As String, urlPost As String

Dim sCase As String
sCase = "192160470"

Set bot = New ChromeDriver

With bot
    .Start "Chrome"

    'First Window (Main Window)
    .Get "https://www.kuwaitcourts.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp"
    '.FindElementById("txtCaseNo").SendKeys sCase
    .FindElementByCss("input[type=text][name='txtCaseNo']").SendKeys sCase

    'MsgBox "Click OK After Entering Captcha", 64


    Stop
    .Quit
End With

End Sub
```

and here's the HTML part for that element

```html
<td><input type="text" name="txtCaseNo" id="txtCaseNo" maxlength="9" class="inputTextBox" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);"></td>
```

I am stuck at this line

```
.FindElementByCss("input[type=text][name='txtCaseNo']").SendKeys sCase
```

Thanks advanced for any help or any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username**  field as the the desired element are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  With bot
      .Start "Chrome"
      .Get "https://www.kuwaitcourts.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp"
      .SwitchToFrame "searchCaseDiv"
      .FindElementByCss("input[type=text][name='txtCaseNo']").SendKeys sCase
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to send text with in the username field within an iframe using Selenium VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848281/how-to-send-text-with-in-the-username-field-within-an-iframe-using-selenium-vba/59848433#59848433)

---

### tl; dr

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got this line `.SwitchToFrame.FindElementById("searchCaseDiv", timeout:=10000)` in red so it may be incorrect. I am not sure

Comment: I used this `.SwitchToFrame "searchCaseDiv"` and this worked fine for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The element is inside of an `iframe` with id *searchCaseDiv*. You have to switch to that iframe to be able to access the element.

Use `.SwitchToFrame` to switch frame.

For java, it would be like this,

```java
driver.switchTo().frame("searchCaseDiv");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but in fact I am interested in VBA. But of course I knew the idea and apply it in VBA `.SwitchToFrame "searchCaseDiv"`