# How to send text with in the username field within an iframe using Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am attempting to login in [the linked website](https://mbwebedi.mahle.com/webedi/jsp/index.jsp). It looks straightforward and I have done this successfully in other websites. I can login manually. My code is

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "https://mbwebedi.mahle.com"
bot.Get "/webedi/jsp/index.jsp"
bot.FindElementByName("Login").SendKeys "ABC123"
```

I receive the error:

```
"NoSuchElementError Element not found for Name=Login"
```

The element's text is:

```
<input class="loginInput" type="text" name="Login" maxlength="30">`
```

I can proceed manually at this point, so I don't think focus is the issue. What I am doing wrong?

[image: The screen with element inspection open]

Comment: I tried both your strategies and I received the "NoSuchElementError".

Comment: Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username** field as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so youhave to:

- First `SwitchToFrame`.
- Then locate the element.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `FindElementByCss`:

    ```
    bot.SwitchToFrame "liefercontent"
    bot.FindElementByCss("input.loginInput[name='Login']").SendKeys "ABC123"
    ```
  - Using `FindElementByXPath`:

    ```
    bot.SwitchToFrame "liefercontent"
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='loginInput' and @name='Login']").SendKeys "ABC123"
    ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Element doesn't exist although it has ID attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075048/element-doesnt-exist-although-it-has-id-attribute/57075258#57075258)

---

### tl; dr

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the help.