# Close pop up within iframe using Selenium and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, iframe

I want to download the video, but there is a problem
I am trying to close popped up

[image]

the code i used has not worked
this is my code

```
Sub Close_Pop_up()
    With New ChromeDriver
        .Get "https://snaptik.app/en/"
        .FindElementById("url").SendKeys ("https://www.tiktok.com/@funny_v.i.p/video/7020796826760547590")
        .FindElementById("submiturl").Click
        .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/article/div[2]/div/a[1]/span/span").Click
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", TimeOut:=10000)
        .FindElementById("dismiss-button").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

this is the html code

```html
<div class="ns-dws4v-e-6 close-button" id="dismiss-button" x-ns-dws4v-e="6" x-overflow-forbidden="xy" aria-label="Close ad" tabindex="1"><div class="ns-dws4v-e-7 close-text" x-ns-dws4v-e="7"><span class="ns-dws4v-e-8" dir="auto" x-ns-dws4v-e="8" x-score="1">Close</span></div></div>
```

can anyone give a good idea ?

Comment: What does `has not worked` entail? Did you get an error message? Did nothing happen? ......

Comment: element not found for id=dismiss-button

Comment: Are you sure that you need to switch?

Answer (score 0):

There are total ***12*** [**ifames**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) within the page and you need to identify the specific [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075048/element-doesnt-exist-although-it-has-id-attribute/57075258#57075258) you intend to switch.

### Solution

```
Sub Close_Pop_up()
    With New ChromeDriver
    .Get "https://snaptik.app/en/"
    .FindElementById("url").SendKeys ("https://www.tiktok.com/@funny_v.i.p/video/7020796826760547590")
    .FindElementById("submiturl").Click
    .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/article/div[2]/div/a[1]/span/span").Click
    .SwitchToFrame "ad_iframe"
```

Comment: the above code doesn't work 

Frame not be found ,
https://ibb.co/gvpBt5Y